# How to make a UITableViewCell that inherits from another UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, inheritance

I created a UITableViewCell that is basically a card with a shadow behind it. I want to make this the base class used for all other custom UITableView Controllers. However, when I used the code below, the Shadowed Card doesn't show up. Why is this?

**ShadowCardTableViewCell**

```
class ShadowCardTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    let borderView = UIView(frame: .zero)
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        changeToShadowedCard()
        self.contentView.layoutIfNeeded()
     }

     required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
       super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
    
    func changeToShadowedCard() {
        backgroundColor = .clear
        contentView.addSubview(borderView)
        borderView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            borderView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.topAnchor, constant: 10),
            borderView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -10),
            borderView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.rightAnchor, constant: -10),
            borderView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.leftAnchor, constant: 10),
        ])
        borderView.backgroundColor = .secondarySystemBackground
        borderView.layer.cornerRadius = 7.5
        borderView.addShadow(shadowColor: UIColor.label.cgColor, shadowOffset: CGSize(width: 0, height: 0), shadowOpacity: 0.3, shadowRadius: 4)
    }
}
```

**OtherTableViewCell**

```
class OtherTableViewCell: ShadowCardTableViewCell {

    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
     }

     required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
       super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your `addShadow(...)` func doing?

Comment: And... are you registering the cell in code via `tableView.register(OtherTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "otherCell")`? Or are you setting the class in a Storyboard Prototype cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't shown what your `borderView.addShadow(...)` func is doing, but this is working fine for me:

```
class ShadowCardTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    let borderView = UIView(frame: .zero)
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        changeToShadowedCard()
        // this line shouldn't be needed
        //self.contentView.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        // this line needed if setting the cell class as a Prototype in Storyboard
        changeToShadowedCard()
    }
    
    func changeToShadowedCard() {
        backgroundColor = .clear
        contentView.addSubview(borderView)
        borderView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            borderView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.topAnchor, constant: 10),
            borderView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -10),
            borderView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.rightAnchor, constant: -10),
            borderView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.leftAnchor, constant: 10),
        ])
        borderView.backgroundColor = .secondarySystemBackground
        borderView.layer.cornerRadius = 7.5
        
        // not sure what you are doing here
        //borderView.addShadow(shadowColor: UIColor.label.cgColor, shadowOffset: CGSize(width: 0, height: 0), shadowOpacity: 0.3, shadowRadius: 4)

        // but this seems to work fine
        borderView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.label.cgColor
        borderView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
        borderView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3
        borderView.layer.shadowRadius = 4
    }
}

class OtherTableViewCell: ShadowCardTableViewCell {
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}

class SubCellVC: UITableViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // if you have not set your cell as a Storyboard Prototype
        //  register it here
        tableView.register(OtherTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "otherCell")
        
        tableView.rowHeight = 60
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 20
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "otherCell", for: indexPath)
        return cell
    }

}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you cannot make UITableViewCell a base class for a UiViewController.
What you can do is provide an extension for you UITableViewCell, something along these lines:

```
extension UITableViewCell {
    func setShadow() {
        layer.shadowColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        layer.shadowOpacity = 0.25
        layer.borderColor = UIColor.separator.cgColor
        layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        layer.cornerRadius = 10
        layer.shadowRadius = 1.0
        layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 1.0, height: 1.0)
    }
}
```

and after registering a cell and initializing it, call it like:

```
cell.setShadow()
```